# How do I fix the intersection of two vector lines in Sketch?

Tags: vector, sketch-app

I am new to graphic design and am using the Sketch app to create some simple geometric shapes.  I've placed two lines in such a way that they overlap at a point and I want it its interaction to look clean but instead it looks like this.

How do I fix up this issue without having to resort to raster graphics?  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select lines then change the ending of the lines:

[image]

You will get the desired result:
[image]